# how do I use useCallback hook in svelte

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, svelte

This is my code block looks line when used with a `useCallback` hook in react but I want to use same function in svelte,but want to add this in useCallback hook. Is there any alternative for svelte.

```
const newCancelToken = useCallback(() => {
        axiosSource.current = axios.CancelToken.source();
        return axiosSource.current.token;
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep that in mind: **The way svelte processes its components is very different from react**.

React re-renders all components any time any state within a component, or anywhere in a parent, changes. To avoid the re-computation you will need the use of `useMemo` or `useCallback` in your case.

Svelte is a compiler and analyzes your template to create targeted DOM update code whenever any **concerned** state changes. With that in mind, you don't need to memoize such functions with svelte.

Answer (score 0):

The svelte equivalent of useMemo/useCallback is $:

// react
const a = useMemo(() => b + c, [b, c]);

// svelte
$: a = b + c;

https://twitter.com/sveltejs/status/1221788690722304003